# Running a c program from command prompt with Windows 10 and Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to run a simple program from command prompt for educational prupose to demonstrate the parameter exchange between a c program and operating system. I got the following output.

[image: Commoand Prompt Output]

I implemented the following code. Please ignore some of the printf outputs. They're written in German. I know I run the program with less parameter. The output should be a hint on program was run with less parameter instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 4)
        printf("Das Programm wurde mit %d anstatt den notwendigen 4 Parametern "
               "gestartet.", argc);
    else {
        int modus      = atoi(argv[1]);

        double niveau  = atof(argv[2]);

        char datei[13];
        size_t strlcpy = strlcpy(datei, argv[3], (int)sizeof(datei) - 1);

        printf("\n\nMAIN-Parameter");
        printf("\n#Parameter:\t%d", argc);
        printf("\nProgrammname:\t%s", argv[0]);
        printf("\nModus:\t%d", modus);
        printf("\nNiveau:\t%f", niveau);
        printf("\nDatei:\t%s", datei);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate your input.

Cheers

Comment: You have to compile it.

Comment: You have to compile your program before you can run it. Cheers ähm, prost.

Comment: `size_t strlcpy = strlcpy(datei, argv[3], (int)sizeof(datei) - 1);` is incorrect because you have a variable and a function with the same name. Also for `strlcpy` (the BSD libc library function), you do not need to subtract 1 from destination buffer size as `strlcpy` will ensure the resulting destination string gets null terminated. You should probably replace that with something like `size_t n = strlcpy(datei, argv[3], sizeof(datei));`.

Answer (score 0):

Install gcc and some other compiler tools into your cygwin:

```
C:\cygwin64>setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel
```

Open a cygwin terminal. Compile your source:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
```

Run your binary with the arguments:

```
$ ./main 1 2 date
```